# Android auto enable bluetooth -> app needs restart for working properly with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-activity

I wrote a little app to communicate with a bluetooth device. When I starty the app, bluetooth will be enabled automatically. I do this with this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();  
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}
```

But directly after auto enabling bluetooth I can't use bluetooth in my app. I have to restarting the app or turning the screen that my app works properly.

I tried this workaround to restart the activity after enabling bluetooth:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    finish();
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

But my app will only closed and not started again. Has anybody an idea how to fix this problem, that I can't use bluetooth, when I enable it with the app start?

Thanks

Cheers

Felix

Answer (score 1):

"But directly after auto enabling bluetooth I can't use bluetooth in my app."

It takes a little time for Bluetooth to be enabled.  You should be listening for the BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED intent to see when the adapter is actually enabled.